# date command calculating one month before from given variable

Tags: shell, date, variable

if there is no argument i can generate the current month and year(*012021*) and lastmonth(*122020*) with "-d 'last month'" option.
if I entered argument like "*01/01/2019*" i can handle $currentmonth(*012019*) but not $pastmonth variable.
is there any way to solve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] ;then
currentmonth=`date "+%m%Y"`
pastmonth=`date "+%m%Y" -d 'last month'`
echo $currentmonth
echo $pastmonth
else
currentmonth=`date +%m%Y --date="$1"`
pastmonth=?
echo $currentmonth
echo $pastmonth
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by “adding” “last month” to the date:

```
date +%m%Y -d "01/01/2019+last month"
```

Beware of [`date`’s parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html), for dates with slashes it assumes US format.